# Obj-C - Filter NSMutableArray with multiple objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently filtering an NSMutableArray (neighbourUIDs) with a value, but I now want to filter the same array with a second string as well, **e.g.**

```
 [predicateString appendFormat:@"SELF.neighbourhood ==[c] '%1$@' OR %@", neighbourUIDs[i], hq];
```

That being said, when I attempt to write the above, XCode throws me the following error:

> Cannot mix positional and non-positional arguments in format string

Any idea how I can accomplish this? See current code below:

**ViewController.m**

```
           NSMutableArray *neighbourUIDs = [self.currentUser valueForKey:@"neighbourhood"];
                NSMutableString *predicateString = [NSMutableString string];

                for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [neighbourUIDs count]; i++) {
                    if (i != 0) {
                        [predicateString appendString:@" OR "];
                    }

      NSString *hq = @"Headquarters";

                    [predicateString appendFormat:@"SELF.neighbourhood ==[c] '%1$@'", neighbourUIDs[i]];


                }

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
          self.closeByNeighbours = [[self.neighbourData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Use `NSCompoundPredicate`
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate/1417873-orpredicatewithsubpredicates?language=objc ? Else: `"SELF.neighbourhood ==[c] '%1$@' OR SELF.neighbourhood ==[c] %@", neighbourUIDs[i], hq]`

Comment: @Larme I still get thrown the same error I mention above when I try to use NSCompoundPredicate (and a crash when I attempt to run it).

Comment: In pseudo code: https://pastebin.com/Mwt88LrB What was the crash log when you tried with compound predicate? What's `neighbourUIDs`? An array of Strings?

Comment: @Larme Tried again - your code block appears to work for the most part, however, SELF.neighbourhood == [c] '%1$' isn't returning a value anymore :/

Comment: Ahh never mind @Larme - did a little tinkering and your code block works like a charm! Thank you :) If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is using the positional parameter $1 in one format argument, but then not using $2 in the second.  You need to either use positional parameters on all %- arguments, or none of them.  But you do also need to use Larme's form (i.e. "key == %@ OR key = %@").